# How to have something like angularjs ng-bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-bind

I want to have something like `angularjs` `ng-bind`, is there a JavaScript or jQuery plugin to do this?
I don't want to implement myself. for example if a developer write this code in a html page:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="user.class.name" value="test user" />
```

I want to read `data-bind` attribute and then create a JavaScript like this:

```
var user = {
    class : {
        name : 'test user'
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with jquery plugin for it, but its 1 line of code via jquery, so why not? if you want an html binding library than you have to use some framework like angular (there are many).

Comment: @sagie, what is the jquery code to do this?

Comment: You mean to say, you don't wanted to use angular, but you want `ng-bind` feature there?